# T SQL alias column name based on query from a table

Tags: t-sql

I have to display a column name from a select query from table, e,g, 'Column 1' is stored in table table1, I want to display 'Column 1' as column name. I cannot hardcode 'Column 1' as it might be unknown when the code is developed.

```
Column 1    Column 2
a           b
```

Any idea?

**Update**

It allows user to define column name.

It has to generate via T SQL

Answer (score 2):

Add alias as a separate column or use dynamic SQL

This doesn't make sense because doing you *should* know what the column is called: you don't store information about columns and build queries on your own metadata

Comment: could you give example or link please? It allows user to define column name.

Comment: +1 - If the name of the field is dynamic, change it in the presentation layer not at the DB level

Comment: @Pingpong - you aren't listening - that is an antipattern and should be avoided.  What `SQL` calls the columns is irrelevant to your presentation layer.

Answer (score 2):

IF you don't know the name of the column at design time, then use a resource file or similar in the presentation layer to hold the value that you will display as the label for column1.  It should be noted, however, you are going to have a very hard time writing any code if you don't know the names of the columns in your database, unless you are select * on everything.

Answer (score 1):

Column names are fairly restricted and should be named with the SQL admin and application developer as the user of the names.   It is not the intent of a column name to be descriptor for the end user interface.

```
 Select dbColumn1 as [Customer Name] from tableMain
```

Even that is not a good practice and then user input is part of the TSQL and you are opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks and it is just not very good control on you query.  A better practice is to pass parameters.